# Error: TypeName property is missing in a field type definition

Tags: custom-field-types

My Windows Application event log continues to show me the error:

> "TypeName property is missing in a field type definition."

I am setting the TypeName property in the fldtypes_MyCustomField.xml file so I don't see what the problem is. Why is SharePoint unhappy now?

Comment: Tying unresolved internet threads together.  Same error's discussed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/379a585c-61ac-474b-8c67-243afd6b46f9/typename-property-is-missing-in-field-type-definition?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy